# I am facing error in my custom HTML which is to push text on a web page using GTM

Tags: html, document.write

I have a very basic and most probably a noob question.

I want to push few set off banners or text on certain web pages. These are messages which user sees on certain conditions and I am trying to achieve this using a custom HTML code in GTM.

The code I explored was from few blogs where using document.write I can push the banner or text on website. The code is below but not sure if its correct as it constantly throws error on line 12, character 2, parse error '}' expected but I am very new in this.

Code is this

```
<script>
(function(){
 
 var country = {{Country and Language}};
 
 if ((country == be-nl));
   
  {  
   document.write('Please come later.');
  }
  
  else if ((country == be-fr)); //error is at this line as mentioned above
   
  {  
   document.write('See you soon, Nothing here.');
  }
  
  else if ((country == nl-nl));
  
  {  
   document.write('Thanks for shopping with us.');
  }
  
  else country == '(not set)';
  })();
  
</script>
```

Comment: What is `{{Country and Language}}` expected to do? Also, `;` after your `if` will prevent the statement below executing. I would recommend using any code editor, they will point out simple syntax issues like this.

Comment: Hi, yes that is a variable which is based on which country and location it should fire. And thanks for the error which you notified. It worked.